# Column chart: Set background of exactly one column

Tags: highcharts

Does anybody know, if it is possible to set a background color of one specific column?

In the following example, the column background color comes onhover, but for all the columns:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

In my case, I would need a fixed column with such a background.

Comment: Do you want it on hover or always?

Comment: If you're looking for always, look at xAxis.plotBands

Comment: always, thanks, i'll try plotbands.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arwe37ya/1/ Do you want to achieve something similar to this example?

Answer (score 0):

You can set color per point to achieve this.

```
series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
    y: 216.4,
    color: '#BF0B23'
    }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/point/color/

**API on series.data.color:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.color